# how to use inheritance for inheriting properties form multiple classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, multiple-inheritance

well, I have few classes (Employee, Leaves,Shift,Weekly_off). I want to Access the leaves of employee by using Employee Class object. same for Leaves and others. So please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for composition, not inheritance:

```
public class Employee
{
    public List<Leave> Leaves { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It had not given me complete solution but given me a trick for using Collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you upper cast you type like:

```
Employee emp = new EmployeeDerived();
```

But *for real* it would be obviously still leaf type.